# r.article_set.all() does not make a query through .objects whereas returns a query

Tags: django

In Django's tutorial,[Django at a glance | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/overview/)

`r.article_set.all()` does not make a query through `.objects` whereas returns a query.

It's quick example:

```
#mysite/news/models.py

from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.full_name

class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.headline
```

Working in Django shell,

```
# Create a new Reporter.
>>> r = Reporter(full_name='John Smith')
# And vice versa: Reporter objects get API access to Article objects.
>>> r.article_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Article: Django is cool>]>
```

Return a QuerySet,even if a `Managers` is not called.

I search through the documentation and learn that A Manager is the interface through which database query operations are provided to Django models. At least one Manager exists for every model in a Django application.

So I can understand:

```
>>> Article.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Article: Django is cool>]>
```

Django adds a Manager with the name objects to every Django model class. [Managers | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager)

As for `r.article_set.all()`, it does not make a query through `.objects` whereas returns a query.

`article_set` is neither the attribute of `Reporter` or `django.db.models.Model`

```
In [3]: hasattr('article_set', 'models.Model')
Out[3]: False
```

How does it work? or provide me a hint so I can explore further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes through [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager)

> A “related manager” is a manager used in a one-to-many or many-to-many
>   related context.

It is automatically added as part of each related field name so in your case Article has ForeignKey on Reporter which gives Reporter ability to get article_set same as to Article to get Reporter object (ex: `article.reporter`).

Additionally interesting info on how to do the [custom reverse manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager)

Also don't be afraid to dig into Django source code to get better idea of how does it exactly work

Comment: Thx very much for your encourage.